# Bound for a random matrix and a normal distributed random vector

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random-matrices, principal-component-analysis

In the topic of [Principal component analysis in high dimensions](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108627771) I have given the following task:

> Let $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times d}$ and $w\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2I_n)$.
>
> Show that for any $\lambda>0$ we have: $$\mathbb
>  P\left(\bigg\|\frac{X^T
>  w}n\bigg\|_\infty\geq\lambda\right)\leq2e^{-\frac{n\lambda^2}{2\sigma^2}+\log(d)}$$

can someone give me a hint?